# в Java hashTable.hashCode() всегда возвращает 0

Tags: java, коллекции, структуры-данных, hashcode

Есть структура(класс).

```
    public class Node {
        private static String separator = "\\";
        private Map<String, Node> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
        private Node parent;
        private String absolutePath;
        private Integer hash;
        public void addFile(File file) {

        fileMap.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), new Node(file.getAbsolutePath(), this));
            hash = hashCode();
        }

        public Node(String absolutePath, Node parent) {
            this.absolutePath = absolutePath;
            this.parent = parent;
        }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Node)) return false;

        Node node = (Node) o;

        if (getFileMap() != null ? !getFileMap().equals(node.getFileMap()) : node.getFileMap() != null) return false;
        return getAbsolutePath().equals(node.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        boolean eq = getFileMap() != null;
        int result;
        if (eq){
            result = getFileMap().hashCode();
            result += 0;
        } else
            result = 0;
        result = 31 * result + getAbsolutePath().hashCode();
        return result;
    }
```

Данная структура используется для представление иерархии файловой системы. То есть node может содержать сам файл, так и hashTable (fileMap) с вложенными файлами, если это директория, также файлы в hashTable (fileMap) могут быть файлами или директориями.

Специально переопределил метод hashCode() через if для наглядности.
**Строка `result = getFileMap().hashCode();` всегда возвращает 0, сколько бы разных сущностей в ней не было.**
В итоге hash считается только от параметра "absolutePath". Что меня не устраивает, ведь мне нужно, чтобы хэш был разным в зависимости от вложенных файлов. 
Иначе получается ситуация в которой, два дерева представляющих файловую систему, например:

testdir/innerdir/1/2

testdir/outdir

и содержащие одинаковую папку в root - "testdir" равны, т.к. хэш вложенных структур в hashTable не учитывается.
Может кто-нибудь сказать Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 5):

Если посмотреть в исходный код `HashMap` (точнее его родителя `AbstractMap`),то можно увидеть как реализовано метод `hashCode()`.Он суммирует хеш коды всех элементов:

```
public int hashCode(){
    int h=0;
    Iterator<Entry<K, V>>i=entrySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext())
        h+=i.next().hashCode();
    return h;
}
```

Далее смотрим как реализуют этот метод элементы `HashMap` - `HashMapEntry`:

```
public final int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getKey()) ^ Objects.hashCode(getValue());
}
```

Здесь используется исключающее ИЛИ для хешкодов ключа и значения. То есть, если хешкоды ключа и значение будут равны, то метод вернёт 0.

В итоге получаем, что когда `getFileMap() == null`, то для этого Node хешкод берётся от `getAbsolutePath()`. Этот же `getAbsolutePath()` является ключём в мапе, получается, что хешкоды ключа и значения равны, отсюда и возвращается 0.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!
Не посмотрел реализацию хэшкода у HashMapEntry.
Данная реализация без переопределения не даст мне определять хэш-код у всей структуры, может быть подскажите идеи, как это обойти?

Comment: А когда getFileMap() != null у нас ведь не должен возвращаться 0?
Интересно почему создатели сделали именно такую реализацию

Comment: @Mr.Ki.D. Если `getFileMap() != null`, то вычисляется его хешкод. У его value `Node` - `getFileMap() == null`. Либо на следующем уровне вложенности. То есть на каком-то последнем уровне будет null, и оттуда пойдёт 0 на самый верх. Как обойти, нужно подумать.